# ASP.NET Multi-Application Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, structure

I need some advice on how I should structure my files for easier publishing and management of codes.

There's 1 website (front-end website), and 1 web application (Content Management System) in a solution, what I want to do is when I publish the solution, the Web App (CMS) files and contents should go into a subfolder of the website folder (e.g. www.domain.com/cms). Is there any way to do this?

I'm using VWD2010Express.

EDIT: Im using a N-Tier structure web application for the CMS system, and just a normal website project for the front-end

Comment: Ummm, just create a folder within the solution called `CMS` and save all related content there?

Comment: Hello, the CMS web application should able to be reused on multiple projects. So I'm separating it from the website directory. (e.g. whenever I have a client who wants a website, I'll just create a blank website project, add the CMS solution into the website project. Once I build the project, the CMS Application should be published onto the website subfolder called CMS)

Comment: Sounds like you want to create separate solution in your project then that consists of DAL/Objects for your CMS system? Then you would just have a folder named `CMS` in the website directory which would implement the functionality from the CMS project...

Comment: No that's not it. I wanna separate the CMS folder from the Website folder. So when I create a new Website Project, I'll add the CMS into the solution and when I build the website, the CMS application should go into the Website sub-folder named CMS. Instead of having to Copy-paste the CMS folder.